# Is possible create a css class name with numbers "from-to"?

Tags: html, css

I need to have 3 classes as follow:

```css
.class-4, .class-5, .class-6 {
    color: pink;
}
```

And it works perfectly.
Let's say I need the same but for 100:

```css
.class-4, .class-5, .... .class-100 {
    color: pink;
}
```

Is there anything similar to this or any other way to do this which I can use.

```css
.class->3<101 {
    color: pink;
}
```

To get the same result without writing 97 times the class and the comma?

Comment: What situation would ever need that many individual classes? Anyways try `[class^="class-"]`

Comment: If you find yourself writing 100 classes for the same style then you need to rethink your logic. Something else need to be fixed instead of finding how to do this.

Comment: Many images numbered from a php function, depending on the number of the image need a different size, for example 1 to 4 width 800px, 5 to 12 400px, 13 to 29 200px and so on till 100, so not really 100 the same but many classes to be repeated. Please explain [class^="class-"]

Comment: *Many images numbered from a php function, depending on the number of the image need a different size* --> this is what need to be fixed, your PHP function to generate a better HTML markup. Updated the logic of your PHP function, don't try to implement this logic in CSS

Comment: In this project I am not allowed to modify php

Comment: So are you saying you cannot alter the HTML? Would you be allowed to use JavaScript?

Comment: Yes adding JavaScript is OK and also HTML, just not change php functions

Comment: `[class^="class-"]` will select all classes that start with `"class-"` If you want a range, ex. `[class^="class-1"]` would select `.class-1`, and `.class-10` through `.class-19`, and `.class-100`. Not that accurate can't imagine `.class-1` would be in the same range as `.class-100`. But considering your limitations, I'd use JavaScript, because algorithms will be your best friend.

Comment: Thanks zer00ne, I will give it a try and let you all know

Comment: so many class with the same rules to apply ? you did it the other way round . So many element with the same style = all of those with the same class .  One would use ID , not CLASS if it has to be unique. One class for each shared rules is to be used (that's the purpose of class) . You may also use data-attributes , if that helps you sorting out common rules and specific cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in pure CSS which will do this, but you could use JavaScript to create a stylesheet for you which has all that tedious repetition created automatically.

In this snippet you say what the ends of the class ranges are and what styling is to be put in each of the ranges.

If there is a range which you don't want to alter then you still need to include it but make its styles string just an empty string.

The snippet runs through each of the ranges creating the relevant style sheet entries and puts them in a style element in the head element of the document.

A few fairly random divs are shown here just to test that we are hitting the right ranges.

```js
const rangeEnds = [4, 20, 35, 41, 48, 100];
const styles = ['color: pink;', 'color: red; background-color: black;', 'color: green;', 'color: yellow;', 'color: blue;', 'color: black; background: pink;'];

let lastRangeEnd = 0;
const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
for (let i = 0; i < rangeEnds.length; i++) {
  for (let j = lastRangeEnd + 1; j < rangeEnds[i]; j++) {
    styleEl.innerHTML += '.class-' + j + ',';
  }
  styleEl.innerHTML += '.class-' + rangeEnds[i] + '{' + styles[i] + '}';
  lastRangeEnd = rangeEnds[i];
}
document.querySelector('head').append(styleEl);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Classes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="class-1">ABCD</div>
  <div class="class-19">ABCD</div>
  <div class="class-21">ABCD</div>
  <div class="class-40">ABCD</div>
  <div class="class-41">ABCD</div>
  <div class="class-48">ABCD</div>
  <div class="class-100">ABCD</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks to everybody anyway for the general learning

Answer (score 0):

If all elements will have the same property which is {color:pink}
You can create only one class (lets call it .pink)

```
.pink {
    color: pink;
}
```

and then you can simply give your elements the .pink class.

Comment: Hello, you should rephrase your answer, as is , your advise is not understood ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of `class` attribute's main purpose is to define a shared style reference name. It is rather not a very good practice to want to reference multiple `class` references and let them share the same styling.

The best way to get around this is to have a common `class` attribute name `YourClassName`. This way, any element you want the styling applied to can have that class appended to its `class` attribute through `element.classList.add(YourClassName)` with JS. And, that would solve all the hussle of having to worry about putting multiple classe names and I cannot think of any 1 situation that would force you to declare each element class separated by commas provided that they are to receive the same styling.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks if it’s possible to have a ‘number range’ (array) at the end of CSS classes that shares the same name, but ending on 1, 2, 3, etc.

As @zer00ne pointed out; You can target multiple classes with one "class". When defining your class selector - leave out the numbers, but make the class name unique.

So, if the class names are i.e. `my-row-class-1`, `my-row-class-2`, etc., write the selector like this;

```
[class^="my-row-class-"] {
    color: pink;
}
```

Pro tip: Instead of using `class^=` selector, it's possible to do this for `id^=` as well - and more. Check out the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more info.